# Не вешаются обработчики событий на WP Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom, gutenberg

Делаю лендинг на WP. Каждая секция, кроме хедера и футера, у меня является отдельным блоком Gutenberg.

Блоки регистрирую с помощью плагина [Block Lab](https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-lab/).

Весь сss и js у меня общий на весь сайт, а не отдельный для каждого блока. js подключается в футере вот так:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method(){
    wp_enqueue_script('maps', 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU', false, null ,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main', THEME_PATH . 'js/scripts.min.js', false, null ,true);
}
```

(`THEME_PATH` - это моя константа в которой хранится урл. Проблема не с путями)

Проблема в том, что после натяжки у меня слетают обработчики событий с элементов, которые должны вешаться при загрузке страницы.

Скорее всего - скрипт отрабатывает до того как все эти элементы появляются в DOM.

Из-за чего такой баг и как поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо прописать зависимость от скриптов блочного редактора

```
wp_enqueue_script('maps', 'https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU', array( 'underscore' ), null ,true);
wp_enqueue_script('main', THEME_PATH . 'js/scripts.min.js', array( 'underscore' ), null ,true);
```

Comment: Попробовал. Это не помогло

Comment: undersocre может и не стартовать, да. Посмотрите в Ctrl+U, какие скрипты запускаются последними. Надо привязаться к ним. К `wp-embed`, например. Или к скриптам этого плагина.

Comment: К какому скрипту по факту привязались?

Comment: ни к какому. Корень проблемы был закопан глубоко в разметке, а скрипты подгружались корректно